# Repeated asking of user input w/ Node?

Tags: node.js

very new to JS/Node here. I'm trying to write a very simple Node program to repeatedly ask the user to type in names of diners until he/she types the keyword `done`. I am using the prompt npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt).

```
var prompt = require('prompt');

// Start the prompt
prompt.start();

var currentDinerName = "";
var done = false;

while (done !== true) {
    // Ask for name until user inputs "done"
    prompt.get(['name'], function(err, result) {
        console.log('Diner name: ' + result.name);
        currentDinerName = result.name;
        if (currentDinerName === 'done') {
            console.log('We are done.');
            done = true;
        }
    });
}
```

However, I'm getting a memory leak -- it doesn't like this `while` loop. What is the proper way to do this in Node/JS?

Thanks.

Comment: One of the very early things you need to understand in node.js is asynchronous responses.  Your while loop runs until all memory is exhausted with each loop starting a separate call to `prompt()` until you have so many that the system comes crashing down.  `prompt.get()` is async.  It returns immediately and the response in the callback comes some time later. As such, you cannot use a `while()` loop. You have to  invoke the next prompt from the response callback of the previous one.  A bit counter-intuitive for someone only use to synchronous programming, but this you do it in the async world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the prompt code in a function and call it as long as the user is not done:

```
function ask() {
    // Ask for name until user inputs "done"
    prompt.get(['name'], function(err, result) {
        console.log('Diner name: ' + result.name);
        currentDinerName = result.name;
        if (currentDinerName === 'done') {
            console.log('We are done.');
        } else {
            ask();
        }
    });
}

ask();
```

Comment: This works in practice because there can't be that many diners, but in theory it will blow overflow the recursion stack.